# how to set the State on Cell of Material React Table

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-react-table

`I am an angular developer new to react.
I am using Material React Table and here is the table structure
[Material React Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfZub.png)

Enabled the Editing mode and manually changed the 1st cell which updated the state of the table data.
Here is the code.

```
**
import { MaterialReactTable } from "material-react-table";
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(data);

 const handleSaveCell = async (cell, value) => {
    const data = [...tableData];
    data[cell.row.index][cell.column.id] = value;
    setTableData(data);
  };**
```

Now the last column has to be updated by adding all the quarters.
The last column of each row has different set of calculations.
So, I have used **Cell** property of the last column (FY) to calculate the values

```
Cell: ({
          cell,
          column,
          renderedCellValue,
          row: {
            original: { unit, q1, q2, q3, q4, fy },
          },
          table,
        }) => {
          switch (unit) {
            case "totalCost": {
              const val = q1 + q2 + q3 + q4;
              //handleSaveCell(cell, renderedCellValue);
              return val;
            }
            case "Average": {
              const val = (q1 + q2 + q3 + q4) / 4;
              handleSaveCell(cell, val)
              return val;
            }
            default:
              return q4;
          }
```

It throws this error

**Cannot update a component while rendering a different component (`MRT_TableBodyCellValue`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `MRT_TableBodyCellValue`,**

Please help me to resolve this.
`